# How to look up in Linux IP routing table?

Tags: routes

I've been manipulating the Linux routing table by "route add" and "route del". Now  given an IP, how can I know (by typing some command) which gateway/device will it go through?

For example, if I have run:

```
route add -net 192.57.66.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

Is there a command that can tell me if I visit 192.57.66.42, it will go through eth0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should stop using net-tools, because you won't find the answer there. But for iproute:

```
ip route add 192.57.66.0/24 dev eth0
ip route get 192.57.66.42
```

Answer (score 3):

```
netstat -rn
```

when you type this command the system will print a table:

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

now all you need to do in order to understand which packets will go through `eth0` is using "[longest prefix match](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/longest+prefix+match/en-en/)" principal.